# C struct pointer step from first to last element

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Providing struct test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

   struct {
      char* one;
      char* two;
      char* three;
    } test;

    char **ptr = &test.one;
    *ptr = "one";
    *++ptr = "two";
    *++ptr = "three";

    printf ("%s\n", test.one);
    printf ("%s\n", test.two);
    printf ("%s\n", test.three);
}
```

Question: Is there a guarantee that the elements in `test` struct are always in consecutive memory order? (So starting with the first struct element `++ptr` will always point to the next element in the `test` struct?)

Comment: Yes; the elements of a structure are stored in the order they are declared.  What can upset calculations is that there may be gaps (padding) between elements.  It won't happen when they're all the same type.  However, you should ask yourself: if I need to step through the elements sequentially, why am I not using an array?  Arrays are designed for sequential access; structures are not (and writing code to access the elements of a structure sequentially is messy).

Comment: it is more a hypothetical question than anything else, just wanted to get this confirmed as it works basically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in a comment to the question:

> Yes; the elements of a structure are stored in the order they are declared. What can upset calculations is that there may be gaps (padding) between elements. It won't happen when they're all the same type.
>
> *However*, you should ask yourself: if I need to step through the elements sequentially, why am I not using an array? Arrays are designed for sequential access; structures are not (and writing code to access the elements of a structure sequentially is messy).

Some relevant parts of the standard are:

> #### §6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> ¶6 As discussed in 6.2.5, a structure is a type consisting of a sequence of members, whose
>   storage is allocated in an ordered sequence, and a union is a type consisting of a sequence
>   of members whose storage overlap.
>
> ¶15 Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields
>   reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a
>   structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed
>   padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.
>
> #### §6.2.5 Types
>
> ¶20 …
>
> - A structure type describes a sequentially allocated nonempty set of member objects
>     (and, in certain circumstances, an incomplete array), each of which has an optionally
>     specified name and possibly distinct type.

Answer (score 2):

For pointers, most certainly you'll always observe that behaviour, but the only guarantee the C language makes is that the elements are ordered in memory. There might gaps in between to optimize the alignment of the fields (for performance, specially on RISC architectures).

The right way to do this is use the offsetof macro, or make it an array.